# как делать margin в процентах?

Tags: html, css

если у меня есть блок-1 шириной в 1000px, и мне нужно передвинуть левый край блока-2 (с помощью margin-left), с шириной в 200px, от левого края блока-1 на, скажем, 300px но в процентах, то как мне это сделать?

Comment: как понять 300px но в процентах?  в процентах от чего?

Comment: от родительского блока конечно

Answer (score 0):

Обернуть в контейнер и относительно него уже двигать

```
<style>
   #container{
      border:2px solid #ffde00;
      margin:50px;
   }
   #div1{
      border:1px solid #333;
      margin-left:0;
      height:300px;
   }
   #div2{
      border:1px solid #ff0000;
      margin-left:30%;
      height:300px;
   }
</style>
<div id="container">
<div id="div1">
FIRST DIV
</div>
<div id="div2">
SECOND DIV
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: 30% это не 300px

Comment: Задайте для #containet width:1000px. А вообще % - это относительная величина и так делать margin не очень хорошо.

Comment: в этом то и вопрос - задать 300px но в процентах...:))

Comment: Проценты считаются относительно свойства родительского блока. 300px являются 30% от 1000px ширины родительского блока.

Comment: ну я то знаю это - а вот автор вопроса по ходу не понимает что стандартный смартфон 320 физических пикселей и его 300 пикселей это не айс на них

Comment: вопрос был не сделать блок в 30% как 300px, а сделать так, чтобы сам левый отступ второго элемента (у которого ширина 200px) был указан в процентах от родительского блока. То есть в процентах нужно указать отступ от родительского блока, а не сам блок, и вот вопрос в том, как, зная род. блок, суметь найти в процентах левый отступ так, чтобы он занимал N% от 1000px и смог двигать "200px-блок" на 300px вправо с помощью margin-left

Comment: @Степан ответ уже дан - указываете % и это будет процент от ширины родителя.

Answer (score 0):

300пикс делим на экран монитора и умножаем на 100. И получим значение в процентах. После чего вместо процентов пишем vw (1% ширины окна).

То есть: 300/1366 = 0.2196193265 * 100 = 21.96% = 22vw (если округлить)

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).